# RegEx split array (string) with nested array

Tags: arrays, regex, split

I just tried to find something similar to solve the problem by myself but I only have found some "parts" and I don't know how to combine them. So I hope anyone can help me with this. The problem:

I have a string which contains an array with one (or more) nested arrays.

> [1,'a b c',[1,'a b c',"A B C"],"A B C"]

or maybe

> [1,['a b c'],'a',[1,"A B C"],"A B C"]

etc...

What I want to have in my result is the top array splitted up by comma, but have the nested arrays including the commas, but without the brackets.

Eg. for the for the first string:

> [0] -> 1
>
> [1] -> 'abc'
>
> [2] -> 1,'a b c',"A B C"
>
> [3] -> "A B C"

My current regex which provides me the splitted top array is:

> /\[[\w\d\s,'"]+]|[\w\d\s"']+/g

But now I have no idea how to change my regex to "cut" the inner brackets...
I already tried diffent ways by using lookaheads/-behinds, word boundaries, groups, etc. but without any success. So is that even possible? And if yes, how?

Maybe I have chosen the wrong approach, but I need to say I am new to regular expressions so please forgive me if the former is not quite correct.

Comment: What is the language you're using?

Comment: What is the text you're splitting?  It looks something like JSON. What created the text?  If it's a well-known format, and not something you just made up, there's probably existing code to do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String[] parts = string.substring(1,string.length()-1).split(",");
for (int n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) {
    if (parts.charAt(0) == '[') parts[n] = parts[n].substring(1,parts[n].length()-1);
}
```

which literally does what you said

> The top array splitted up by comma, but have the nested arrays without the brackets.

Sometimes, programming can be that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

This split regex is quite ugly but does what you want. From what I can tell by using RegexBuddy, it will only work in .NET.

```
(?<=^\[(?:(?>\[[^\]\[]+(?:\]|(?=\])))|(?>[^\[\]]+))*|^)[,\[\]]+
```

As much as I like to use regular expressions, in this case I think I would go with a small function like the following (written in C#):

```
string[] DeserializeArray(string serializedArray) {
    const char OPEN_GROUP = '[', CLOSE_GROUP = ']', DELIMITER = ',';
    List<string> deserializedArray = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder accumulator = new StringBuilder();
    int nestDepth = 0;
    int baseDepth = serializedArray[0] == OPEN_GROUP ? 1 : 0;
    for(int i=0; i<serializedArray.Length; ++i){
        if(serializedArray[i] == OPEN_GROUP) ++nestDepth;
        else if(serializedArray[i] == CLOSE_GROUP) --nestDepth;
        else if(serializedArray[i] == DELIMITER && nestDepth <= baseDepth) {
            deserializedArray.Add(accumulator.ToString());
            accumulator.Clear();
        }
        else {
            accumulator.Append(serializedArray[i]);
        }
    }
    deserializedArray.Add(accumulator.ToString());
    return deserializedArray.ToArray();
}
```